# Create app id with same bundle id after deleting it from previous developer account

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two developer accounts. `Xcode` automatically created a `wild card` `provisional profile` with bundle id "`com.xyz.abc`" in one of developer account. Now, Is it possible to create/use bundle id "`com.xyz.abc`" in second developer account by deleting the App id created by Xcode in first developer account.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It does register the same bundle id after deleting it from other developer account. I tried registering a same bundle id in another account after deleting it from previously registered developer account.

Comment: Yes, of course we should keep note that whether app is uploaded in iTunes or not. If uploaded we should follow transferring app process

Answer (score 1):

> Important:  If you delete your app, you can’t restore it. The SKU or app name can’t be reused in the same organization. If you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused.

[Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Answer (score 1):

*If you have not uploaded a build and you created the bundle id from xcode without a payed developer account.*
**You can call apple to delete the bundle id.**

*If you have already upload a build.* **Deleting is not possible.**

*If you have an payed apple dev account and you have not uploaded an build.* **You can delete it in your dev account.**

Answer (score 0):

`BundleID` is unique ID by which application can identified. You can not use same `bundle id` . One bundle id can be used only once.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle id can be deleted if you **haven't upload any build** to iTunes Connect using that bundle id.

But if you did it, the only way to use bundle id in other account is to transfer the app from one account to another.

[Transferring and deleting apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

[image]